# Starting memory allocation for JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm beginning use the `-Xmx` option on the `java` command to allow my processes to use a little more memory (256Mb, though I think I'm currently using less than 128Mb).  I've also noticed the `-Xms` option for starting memory, with a default value of 2Mb.  What should I set this value to and why?

---

> [Reference: Java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

Comment: I admit I'm too lazy to [look it up](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp) but my general rule of thumb for questions like this is: If I don't know what the option is good for and nothing's broken, I leave it as is, trusting to the good sense of whoever set the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-Xmx` argument defines the max memory size that the heap can reach for the JVM. You must know your program well and see how it performs under load and set this parameter accordingly. A low value can cause an `OutOfMemoryException` or very poor performance if your program's heap memory is reaching the maximum heap size. If your program is running on a dedicated server you can set this parameter higher because it wont affect other programs.

The `-Xms` argument sets the initial and minimum heap memory size for the JVM. This means that when you start your program the JVM will allocate this amount of memory instantly. This is useful if your program will consume a large amount of heap memory right from the start. This avoids the JVM needing to regularly increase the heap size and so you can gain some performance there. If you don't know if this parameter is going to help you, don't use it.

It is good practice with server-side Java applications like Resin to set the minimum `-Xms` and maximum `-Xmx` heap sizes to the same value.
You can set to 256 or 512Mb.

Comment: My practice is that when I find I have to raise mx for some reason, I make ms match it since it IS hitting that limit (or you wouldn't have had to raise mx).  I'm not sure if this matters, but why not have it allocate it all up front if you know you are going to need it?  If you don't need the high mx for every run though you might leave ms low.

Comment: @Bill yeap, nowadays RAM is a something you can just throw in into a machine. This was more for a time when the app needed to play nice with the rest. If you have the RAM you can give it to java upfront.

Comment: Well, my thought was that under the assumption that you need the ram and have to use your -mx variable anyway, then it follows that you have the ram to use -ms and will eventually need it so where is the negative to setting it up front?

Comment: @Bill. earlier Days we require to worry about this factor

Answer (score 7):

Heap size should be 'right' for your application finding right though isn't easy.  If it's too small you run out of memory if to big you waste memory and will run the risk of having long GC pauses.  When things go wrong (and they always go wrong) the more heap you have the more heap you have to debug and the longer any leaks will take to manifest themselves.

Ideally I would set `-Xms` to be the size I think my application needs to run and `-Xmx` to a value larger than this (but not too large).  Always switch on verbose garbage collection and graph the heap in use to check the values you have set.

When I graph the heap I look at the number of collections occurring and the type.  It's important not to have too many.   However it's also important not to have a heap so huge that there are few, because when they happen (and full gc's are inevitable) they will hurt.  Ideally a regular set of well spaced gcs with very low pause times is being sought.

That said for 32bit Windows `-Xms` should be the same as `-Xmx` this is because Java (leaving aside jrockit) needs contiguous memory and the Windows' memory map is fragmented it therefore pays to get and lock down the heap as early as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Xmx is the upper bound of the memory pool. Xms is the initial size. That's all there's to it. The appropriate size for each would depend on the complexity of your application. The main advantage of setting the initial size higher than 2mb would just be that the JVM would spend less time requesting more memory from the OS. If you've set an upper limit of 256mb, an initial size of 32mb-64mb wouldn't be unreasonable for most enterprise applications.

More here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Answer (score 1):

> *What should I set this value to and why?*

Depends on your application of course.

If you know your application initially consumes up to, let's say 64 mb in the first minute, then using the default ( 2mb), will make the VM request memory several times until it reach this 64mb. These memory requests will slow down a little bit your application, because the garbage collector may run a number of times trying to free space before the VM ask for more.

If you know already that you'll use as start 64 mb, using `-Xms` parameter will let you allocate that memory upfront.

If you're consuming 128mb and you have enough memory available you may use `java -Xms128m` and don't worry about requesting more memory for a long time.

But again, it depends on what your application does, how is the memory used, when is needed. etc. etc.