# Accessing a text file from desktop using JAVA console application

Tags: java, file, console-application, desktop

I have a text file in my desktop named "MyText.txt" and it have some contents in it.

Since i am learning JAVA i thought of simply creating an console application which will read the contents from the txt file and then show it in console.

But since i am new to this ,so i am unable to figure out the way it works.

Can anyone get me into a right direction.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: search google for "java read text file content". you will get lot of help

Comment: have done that already,after that only posted the code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following example to read file character basis.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package io;

import java.io.*;

/**
*
* @author Nandeshwar
*/
public class FileExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inFile = new File("c:/users/toshiba/desktop/MyText.txt");

    FileReader ins = null;

    try {
        ins = new FileReader(inFile);

        int ch;
        while ((ch = ins.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println((char) ch);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            ins.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but how can i read content from a file from desktop by only giving its name,rather than giving hard coded full file name

Comment: String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter file name");
        File inFile = new File(fileName); Write these two lines , instead of File inFile = new..........

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives for doing this. A higher level thing could be using a `Scanner` class. I assume, since you are learning java, you might have come across `Scanner` class for reading the input from console. You can use the `Scanner` same way to read the file also.

You can use `Scanner#nextInt()`, `Scanner#next()`, etc... methods for reading the input. You can use `args[]` array for taking the command line arguments.

Since, you haven't mention exactly what kind of way your data is stored in file, it's hard to give a working example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester { 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
      //use here the functions such as sc.nextInt() and so on
    }
  }
}
```

Link to the docs:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

If you are reading big file in java (see my answer to other question): [file size too big for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044042/file-size-too-big-for-java/17044782#17044782):

**Working Example:**

This program prints the file contents to console.

Execute this program using `java Tester yourFileName` after compilation.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tester { 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      if (args.length > 0) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("No file name given");
      }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Create a `BufferedReader` object like this:

```
new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Location of the file"));
```

Read this doc, for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, i dnt wanna hard code the location of the file,else i want to get file from desktop by passing its name

Comment: Use Scanner class.Take file name as input String and append it to the location. String desktop = "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\"; String inputFile = get it from scanner by calling scanner.nextString(). do String input = desktop + inputFile and pass this input to the constructor.